# shopify deeply nested menu, where to put?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Shopify, out of the box, only supports 3 levels deep menus (welcome to 2021).

What is a good approach to implement deeper nested menus?

things that come to mind:

manually sub-nest menus in the theme files.

E.g. create menu

MAIN

and another menu
MAIN1-LVL2

then put the MAIN1-LVL2 like so

MAIN -> MAIN1-LVL2

same with MAIN2-LVL2

Another approach I thought about putting the menu data into settings_data.json

Is there another good way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to create a recursive snippet that will check if there is a menu dropdown OR an another menu with the same menu title and output the links.

So for example if you have:

```
Navigation Title: Main menu
- Home
- About
- - Company
- - History
- - - Link 1
- - - Link 2
- - People
- Contact

Navigation Title: Company
- Link 1
- Link 2
```

There will be a standard dropdown for the **About** and **History**, but **Company** will render the second menu called with the same name.

If you are worried that you will have name collision you can prefix the menu with `dropdown-` and the snippet will check if the navigation has the same title with the prefix.

This is how most premium themes handles mega menus in Shopify.